# Documentation for DOM command in Browsers' devtools Console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Are there ways to view live documentation for DOM commands on  Browsers' devtools Console? The goal is that I want a faster way than opening a new tab, checking documentation and navigating back to the console.

*Note for editing*: I decided to attach this image to have the question more clarified.
What I am asking about is how to view "documentation of DOM" in console.

[image: D]

Comment: You can remember the commands you use most frequently.

Comment: Probably it's because of my obscure way of using words that results in your misunderstanding of the question. I've edited the question for more clarification. Looking forwards for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to view the documentation of DOM APIs directly within the Chrome or Firefox DevTools.

There are ways to improve the workflow a bit, though. E.g. in Chrome you can install an extension called [MDN-Dox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mdn-dox/bgnmfcaahgpmkicfdfffkbapjjonjhpn/), which adds a toolbar button for searching within the MDN documentation.

Alternatively, you can add MDN web docs to the installed search engines. In Chrome you do that by opening the settings > *Search engine* > *Manage search engines* > *Add* > entering the search engine info with "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=%s" as URL. See https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en for more info.

For Firefox there's also an extension called [MDN Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mdn-search/), which adds "mdn" as keyword to search for something on MDN web docs.

You can also add the search engine manually. One way to do that is to go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ > right-click the search field > *Add a Keyword for this Search* > entering the info. You may also read https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-or-remove-search-engine-firefox.